# Is it possible to test out Oauth Login Authentication (Facebook, Twitter, Google) without a domain and hosting?

Tags: django, oauth, twitter-oauth, oauth-2.0, oauth-provider

Is there a way without actual domain name and a hosting ?

> Can we use localhost in some way ?

I am using Python and Django !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have found out :

**It can be done, simply by using 127.0.0.1 in the callback/redirect uri**

It worked and I am able to test my app on localhost.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use url shorteners to create short urls kind of "localhost:port" and then register that shortened url as the callback url for your app.

FYI: some url shorteners don't allow you to shorten "localhost:port" urls. I suggest you to use [goo.gl](http://goo.gl)

Comment: I have tried it with twitter, but it should work with facebook too

Comment: I am not talking about the url shortning to work, I mean how will you get back a redirect on localhost from twitter or facebook ?

Comment: point the callback url to that link, it will redirect automatically

Comment: Ok, let me try and then I will come back with the result.

Answer (score 2):

I have a domain name and hosting but when I need to try the Oauth Authentication, what I do is:

**Modify the hosts file** to map a random domain to your local ip.

For example in windows, I modify the file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts' adding the following line:

```
127.0.0.1    www.yourdomain.com
```

BTW, this domain doesn't need to be registered

Comment: Yes, it was perfectly with Facebook. But you might need to restart the browser or to press Ctrl + F5